# How to find week number of 4 week rolling cycle by given date in Power Query M

Tags: date, math, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a calendar table build with Power Query and I need to use this to add a column for a 4 week cycle I can track a weekly task.

example

Column A is all dates in sequence from 01/01/2019 up to 31/12/2022

Column B is the week sequence e.g.

01/01/2019 -> 07/01/2019 is 1

08/01/2019 -> 14/01/2019 is 2

04/10/2021 -> 10/10/2021 is 145

If I start from week 145 how would I work out the week number in a 4 week cycle given any date. So if

Week 145 is Task A

Week 146 is Task B

Week 147 is Task C

Week 148 is Task D

Week 149 is Task A and so on.

If I asked for the Task in the 4 week period for Week 158 I would get Task B as it is the second week in the repeating cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood properly what you need. Do you need an additional column indicating the task of the week based on that cycle of 4?

If that is the case I think what you might be looking for is the mod function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powerquery-m/number-mod

Create a new column using mod and dividing by 4.
Then create a if-column based on the result of the Mod-column. If 0 --> "Task A", 1 --> "Task B", etc.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you @Adrian Fischer ,spot on what I needed.
Number.Mod(WeekSequence,4) returns a value of 0,1,2,3 which repeats for each day of the week. With a conditional I can add Task A to all 1's Task B to all 2's etc